# Express/Mongoose Throw new Error not being passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 1 issue working with mongoose while using postman to test my apis.

1. Neither `throw new Error()` from the `userSchema`makes it back to the `route.post` **catch** error.

How do I get either `throw new Error()` to be returned to the `router.post` script?

The script works properly when the email and password matches what's in the database.

If I `console.log(no email)` or `no password` with the perspective `if()` statement, they fire but the `throw new Error()` message does not make it over to the catch statement on the **router.post**. If i **console.log(error)** on **router.post** I get

> Error: No email found 
>       at Function.userSchema.statics.validatePassword (C:\Users\Samson\Documents\JS\nodeProjects\task-manager\src\models\users.js:60:15)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>       at async C:\Users\Samson\Documents\JS\nodeProjects\task-manager\src\routers\user.js:66:22

But what's passed back to postman is `{}`
Below I'll provide the code and screenshots of both the user model, schema and route.post
**Schema Object**

```
    userSchema.statics.validatePassword = async function (email, password) {
    const user = this;
    const userObj = await user.findOne({
        "email": email
    });

    if (!userObj) {
        console.log("no email")
        throw new Error("No email found ");
    }

    const answer = await bcrypt.compare(password, userObj.password);

    if (!answer) {
        console.log("no password")
        throw new Error('Incorrect Password');
    }

    return answer;

}
```

**Mongoose User Modle**

```
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate(name) {
            if (name.length <= 0) {
                throw new Error("Please fill in a name");
            }
        }

    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        validate(age) {
            if (age < 18) {
                throw new Error('Participates must be 18 years of age or older');
            }
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        validate(address) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(address)) {
                throw new Error('Please enter a valid email address');
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        validate(secret) {
            if (secret.length <= 6 || secret.includes('password')) {
                throw new Error("Please select a password longer than 6 characters and that doesn't include the term password");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**router.post**

```
    router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const user = await User.validatePassword(req.body.email, req.body.password);
        res.status(200).send("user and password validated " + user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
userSchema.statics.validatePassword = async function (email, password) {
const user = this;
const userObj = await user.findOne({
    "email": email
});

if (!userObj) {
    return 0
}

const answer = await bcrypt.compare(password, userObj.password);

if (!answer) {
    return -1;
}

return answer;
}
```

router.post

```
router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {

try {
    const user = await User.validatePassword(req.body.email, req.body.password);
if(user == 0){
    return res.status(404).send('no email found')
}
if(user == -1){
    return res.status(404).send('Incorrect Password')
}
    res.status(200).send("user and password validated " + user);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(400).send(error);
}
});
```